# RewriteCond - how to escape this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi am having a problem rewriting this url - how do I escape it so it will correct itself?

The url was sent out into the public domain like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/directory-2/10018485&key=3945
```

I need to write a rule to correct it:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/directory-2/10018485?key=3945
```

`
Am tring to do it like so, without success....

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/directory\/directory-2\/10018485&key=3945
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/directory-2/?id=10018485&key=3945 [L]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: are directory and directory-2 constant? and don't change?

Comment: I thing REQUEST_URI is url encoded. You could just put the regex in the RewriteRule; no need to use RewriteCond. Try this: `RewriteRule ^directory/directory-2/10018485&key=3945$ /directory/directory-2/?id=10018485&key=3945 [L,R]` (I added the R to prevent duplicated content in google). Else try %26 and %3D for `&` and `=` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the & in the match to %26. What you have works fine for me, not sure why it isn't working for you. But you don't need a RewriteCond, you can combine the 2 into a single rule. These work for me when the actual request is `/directory/directory-2/10018485&key=3945` or `directory/directory-2/10018485%26key=3945`

```
RewriteRule ^directory/directory-2/10018485&key=3945$ /directory/directory-2/?id=10018485&key=3945 [L]
```

In a more abstract sense:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/directory-2/([0-9]+)&key=([0-9]+)$ /directory/directory-2/?id=$1&key=$2 [L]
```